# How to create own database in redis?

Tags: redis

```
There are 0 to 15 databases in redis.
```

I want to create my own database using redis-cli.
 Is there any command for it?

Answer (score 67):

Redis database is not an equivalent of database names in DBMS like mysql.
It is a way to create isolation and namespacing for the keys, and only provides index based naming, not custom names like `my_database`.

By default, redis has 0-15 indexes for databases, you can change that number 
`databases NUMBER` in `redis.conf`.

And then you use [SELECT](http://redis.io/commands/SELECT) command to select the database you want to work on.

Answer (score 19):

You don't create a database in Redis with a command - the number of databases is defined in the configuration file with the `databases` directive (the default value is 16). To switch between the databases, call [`SELECT`](http://redis.io/commands/select).

Comment: I think that the default database is `0`, according to the docs that you linked

Answer (score 18):

Use `select`, for example:

```
select 1 
select 2
...
```

Answer (score 7):

I found this relevant when I encountered the same question:

> **Redis different selectable databases are a form of namespacing: all the databases are anyway persisted together in the same RDB / AOF file.** However different databases can have keys having the same name, and there are commands available like FLUSHDB, SWAPDB or RANDOMKEY that work on specific databases.
>
> In practical terms, Redis databases should mainly used in order to, if
>   needed, separate different keys belonging to the same application, and
>   **not in order to use a single Redis instance for multiple unrelated
>   applications.**

The bolding is my addition.

Read more here: https://redis.io/commands/select

For the question of how to select a "database", it is the same answer given here:

```
$ select 1
```

And also some useful stuff about persistence, if RDB/AOF were mentioned: https://redis.io/topics/persistence